# IPad html5 sounds loading runs out of RaM

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, mobile-safari

I need to play 5 soundfiles with a duration of about 1min in a webapplication (html5, webaudioapi/audiotag) on Safari for iPad. All soundfiles are of the same length and the user shall be able to fade them in and out by mouseclick (all sounds shall play at the same time.). On a DesktopPC this already works perfectly.
 The problem is that Safari crashes telling it ran out of RAM during loading of the soundfiles. I already got the userinteraction to be able to load sounds and one part of the webapplication, that is playing sounds by using the same routine as in the case above works, but there it's only playing parts of one soundfile.

Which Javascript-frameworks can handle long soundfiles on IPad? What could I try to make my webapplication run on IPad?

The IPad I'm testing with has IPad/IOS 6.1.3, The crashreport on General>About... of safari is named "LowMemory-....plist", it says im using iPad3,4 tells me that mobilesafari was the largest process and lists all other processes that seems to were running when safari crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem solved when updating to IOS 7. Hope nobody with an older IOS-Version will try to enter the WebApp.